# mixing multiple rtp audio streams with gstreamer

Tags: linux, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I am trying to mix multiple audio udp rtp packets which created with following command on some other computers, but after a lot of searching I could not find some proper command to mix received audios.

I use this command to stream audio on other computers to my computer:

```
gst-launch-1.0 autoaudiosrc ! audioconvert ! rtpL24pay ! udpsink host=<MY_COMPUTER_IP> port=<some_port_number>
```

and I can receive the stream on my computer with this command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=<port_number> caps="application/x-rtp,channels=(int)2,format=(string)S16LE,media=(string)audio,payload=(int)96,clock-rate=(int)44100,encoding-name=(string)L24" ! rtpL24depay ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink sync=false
```

but I want to mix received streams together and play them as one audio in only one pipeline, how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To mix two audio streams you can use GStreamer's [audiomixer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/audiomixer/audiomixer.html?gi-language=c) plugin. Very basic example would be:

**Generator of 2 parallel RTP (over UDP) streams with test audios in different frequencies**

```
gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc freq=523 ! audioconvert ! rtpL24pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000 \
audiotestsrc freq=659 ! audioconvert ! rtpL24pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5001
```

**Receiver of 2 different RTP (over UDP) streams that mixes 2 audios carried by streams**

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp,channels=(int)2,format=(string)S16LE,media=(string)audio,payload=(int)96,clock-rate=(int)44100,encoding-name=(string)L24" \
! queue ! rtpL24depay ! audioconvert ! audiomixer name=mixer ! autoaudiosink \
udpsrc port=5001 caps="application/x-rtp,channels=(int)2,format=(string)S16LE,media=(string)audio,payload=(int)96,clock-rate=(int)44100,encoding-name=(string)L24" \
! queue ! rtpL24depay ! audioconvert ! mixer.
```

Comment: thank you! I have another question now, I had wrote a code based on https://github.com/sdroege/gst-snippets/blob/master/dynamic-tee-vsink.c which creates a pipeline and adds dynamic elements to stream data to some IPs, and I can join or remove any IP to pipeline at any time. So here is my second question, how can I do the same with receiver pipeline?

Comment: comment section is too limited to answer this but in short it would be something like following... adding: create/add/link all elements in new branch, create request sink pad on audiomuxer and link with upstream elements, set elements state to PLAYING. Removing: register blocking probe on udpsrc sink pad, send EOS, set state of downstream elements to NULL, remove downstream elements including audiomuxer's request sink pad.

Comment: thank you for your answers which helped me a lot! I did what I wanted and post their examples on my github: https://github.com/ahmadafkandeh/gstreamer-rtp-streaming/blob/master/README.md